# Can't retrieve image from mongoDB use NODE + mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

Can't retrieve image from mongooDB use NODE + mongoose + multer
After success uploading image on server , which multer, i save image data into mongoDB

its my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const imageSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    desc: String,
    img:
        {
            data: Buffer,
            contentType: String
        }
})

const Image = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
module.exports = Image;


//its my server side

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
        let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '.' + extension)
    }
});

let upload = multer({ storage: storage });



app.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('image'),async (req, res, next) => {
    let extArray = req.file.mimetype.split("/");
    let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
    let obj = {
        name: '1',
        desc: '1',
        img: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: `image/${extension}`,
        }
    }
    await new Image(obj).save().then(image =>{
        res.send(image)
    })


//its my client side 

/*eslint-disable*/

const uploadPicture = () => {
    const uploadButton = document.getElementById('add-picture');

    const pushImage = (event) => {
        let form = new FormData();
        form.append('image', event.target.files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/uploadImage',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form,
        }).then((image) => {

            document.getElementById('added-image').src = `data:${image.img.contentType};base64,${image.img.data.toString('base64')}`;
        })
    }

    uploadButton.addEventListener('change', pushImage, false);




}
export {uploadPicture}



});
```

After i uploaded image, image is saving in folder 'uploads' and saving in mongoo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKkcp.png)

But in browser i get error data:image/jpeg;base64,[object Object]:1 GET data:image/jpeg;base64,[object Object] net::ERR_INVALID_URL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXh5P.png)

Please help me, what i`m doing wrong ?

Im try changed urlencoded to utf-8 but nothing help me

Comment: What do you get if you log `image` in your ajax `then` block?

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying where you're trying to access that image and verify what's the parameter you're passing to access it, maybe you need to access a value inside the object you're receiving from mongodb and sending it to your Api endpoint

Reference: data:image/jpeg;base64,[object Object]:
Explanation: it's not accessing the image itself, it's trying to pass an object as a path

Hope it helps!